# How to make non-frozen dataclass frozen, and vice versa?

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

I want to know a simple way to make a dataclass `bar` frozen.

```py
@dataclass
class Bar:
    foo: int
bar = Bar(foo=1)
```

In other words, I want a function like the following `some_fn_to_freeze`

```py
frozen_bar = some_fn_to_freeze(bar)
frozen_bar.foo = 2 # Error
```

And, an inverse function `some_fn_to_unfreeze`

```py
bar = som_fn_to_unfrozen(frozen_bar)
bar.foo = 3 # not Error
```

Comment: The desire to do this implies serious design issues. If you want to mutate instances, why was the dataclass frozen in the first place? If you want to protect them, why wasn't it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The standard way to mutate a `frozen` dataclass is to use `dataclasses.replace`:

```py
old_bar = Bar(foo=123)
new_bar = dataclasses.replace(old_bar, foo=456)
assert new_bar.foo == 456
```

For more complex use-cases, you can use the dataclass utils module from: https://github.com/google/etils

It add a `my_dataclass = my_dataclass.unfrozen()` member, which allow to mutate `frozen` dataclasses directly

```py
# pip install etils[edc]
from etils import edc

@edc.dataclass(allow_unfrozen=True)  # Add the `unfrozen()`/`frozen` method
@dataclasses.dataclass(frozen=True)
class A:
  x: Any = None
  y: Any = None


old_a = A(x=A(x=A()))

# After a is unfrozen, the updates on nested attributes will be propagated
# to the top-level parent.
a = old_a.unfrozen()
a.x.x.x = 123
a.x.y = 'abc'
a = a.frozen()  # `frozen()` recursively call `dataclasses.replace`

# Only the `unfrozen` object is mutated. Not the original one.
assert a == A(x=A(x=A(x = 123), y='abc'))
assert old_a == A(x=A(x=A()))
```

As seen in the example, you can return `unfrozen`/`frozen` copies of the dataclass, which was explicitly designed to mutate nested dataclasses.

`@edc.dataclass` also add a `a.replace(**kwargs)` method to the dataclass (alias of `dataclasses.dataclass`)

```
a = A()
a = a.replace(x=123, y=456)
assert a == A(x=123, y=456)
```

Answer (score 4):

`dataclass` doesn't have built-in support for that. Frozen-ness is tracked on a class-wide basis, not per-instance, and there's no support for automatically generating frozen or unfrozen equivalents of dataclasses.

While you could try to do something to generate new dataclasses on the fly, it'd interact very poorly with `isinstance`, `==`, and other things you'd want to work. It's probably safer to just write two dataclasses and converter methods:

```
@dataclass
class Bar:
    foo: int
    def as_frozen(self):
        return FrozenBar(self.foo)

@dataclass(frozen=True)
class FrozenBar:
    foo: int
    def as_unfrozen(self):
        return Bar(self.foo)
```

Answer (score 3):

Python dataclasses are great, but the [attrs](https://www.attrs.org/en/stable/index.html) package is a more flexible alternative, if you are able to use a third-party library. For example:

```
import attr

# Your class of interest.
@attr.s()
class Bar(object):
   val = attr.ib()

# A frozen variant of it.
@attr.s(frozen = True)
class FrozenBar(Bar):
   pass

# Three instances:
# - Bar.
# - FrozenBar based on that Bar.
# - Bar based on that FrozenBar.
b1 = Bar(123)
fb = FrozenBar(**attr.asdict(b1))
b2 = Bar(**attr.asdict(fb))

# We can modify the Bar instances.
b1.val = 777
b2.val = 888

# Check current vals.
for x in (b1, fb, b2):
    print(x)

# But we cannot modify the FrozenBar instance.
try:
    fb.val = 999
except attr.exceptions.FrozenInstanceError:
    print(fb, 'unchanged')
```

Output:

```
Bar(val=888)
FrozenBar(val=123)
Bar(val=999)
FrozenBar(val=123) unchanged
```

Comment: `attrs` may be more flexible, but there's nothing here you couldn't do with `dataclass`. For example, the inheritance would have worked with `dataclass` too; I just find it clearer to have separate classes. (Also, `asdict` is dangerous due to confusing recursion and copying behavior.)

Comment: @user2357112 Frozen dataclasses cannot inherit from non-frozen, and vice versa, unless the experiment I just ran had a flaw in it.

Comment: Huh. Looks like you're right. The check doesn't seem to be applied if the parent has no fields, which threw off my first test.

Comment: @FMc very cool! What do you think about implementing tree structure with `attrs`?

Comment: @Yohei Sounds fine. Remember, that the classes generated by `attrs` are regular Python classes.

Comment: I used attrs and found it is very good package, but it is incompatible with linter and typecheckers,,,

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the following code to get a frozen copy of a dataclass class or instance:

```
import dataclasses 
from dataclasses import dataclass, fields, asdict
import typing
from typing import TypeVar


FDC_SELF = TypeVar('FDC_SELF', bound='FreezableDataClass')

@dataclass
class FreezableDataClass:
    @classmethod
    def get_frozen_dataclass(cls: Type[FDC_SELF]) -> Type[FDC_SELF]:
        """
        @return: a generated frozen dataclass definition, compatible with the calling class
        """
        cls_fields = fields(cls)
        frozen_cls_name = 'Frozen' + cls.__name__

        frozen_dc_namespace = {
            '__name__': frozen_cls_name,
            '__module__': __name__,
        }
        excluded_from_freezing = cls.attrs_excluded_from_freezing()
        for attr in dir(cls):
            if attr.startswith('__') or attr in excluded_from_freezing:
                continue
            attr_def = getattr(cls, attr)
            if hasattr(attr_def, '__func__'):
                attr_def = classmethod(getattr(attr_def, '__func__'))
            frozen_dc_namespace[attr] = attr_def

        frozen_dc = dataclasses.make_dataclass(
            cls_name=frozen_cls_name,
            fields=[(f.name, f.type, f) for f in cls_fields],
            bases=(),
            namespace=frozen_dc_namespace,
            frozen=True,
        )
        globals()[frozen_dc.__name__] = frozen_dc
        return frozen_dc

    @classmethod
    def attrs_excluded_from_freezing(cls) -> typing.Iterable[str]:
        return tuple()

    def get_frozen_instance(self: FDC_SELF) -> FDC_SELF:
        """
        @return: an instance of a generated frozen dataclass, compatible with the current dataclass, with copied values
        """
        cls = type(self)
        frozen_dc = cls.get_frozen_dataclass()
        # noinspection PyArgumentList
        return frozen_dc(**asdict(self))
```

Derived classes could overwrite attrs_excluded_from_freezing to exclude methods which wouldn't work on a frozen dataclass.

Why didn't I prefer other existing answers?

- [3rd party libraries - etils.edc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70864709/18009255), If I would use a solution from one of the previous answers, it would be this one. E.g. to get the ability to recursively freeze/unfreeze.
- [3rd party libraries - attrs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56069561/18009255)
- [duplicated code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56069389/18009255)