# How to construct circular referencing instances of a frozen class in python

Tags: python, self-reference, namedtuple, python-dataclasses

I have instances of a dataclass that reference each other.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass()
class Foo:
    id: int
    neighbor: 'Foo'
        
foo = Foo(1, None)
bar = Foo(2, foo)
foo.neighbor = bar
```

I really want a frozen class, since these objects must not be manipulated in a multi threaded run. But if I declare `frozen=True`, the last line will obviously raise an error. I cannot think of a way how to deal with this. I read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56069359/how-to-make-non-frozen-dataclass-frozen-and-vice-versa) but the solution does not work for me, since `foo.neighbor` should point at another frozen instance.

Is there any way to achieve this? I am not bound to dataclasses. But I encounter the same problem using namedtuples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`frozen` works by overriding `__setattr__`. You can by pass `__setattr__` altogether by accessing your instance's `__dict__` attribute directly.

```
foo.__dict__['neighbor'] = bar
```

I don't know if this will have any unintended side effects in general (and certainly won't work if you use `__slots__` to prevent `__dict__` from being created), but it might be sufficient for your use case.

(This may also fail in future versions of `dataclass`, if the implementation changes to use a C extension rather than the current approach of dynamically generating source code to pass to `exec`. `namedtuple` evolved along those lines, I believe.)

---

Or, you can use the same trick that `dataclasses` itself uses to initialize the attributes of a frozen class: use `object.__setattr__` explicitly.

```
object.__setattr__(foo, 'neighbor', bar)
```

Comment: Astonishing how fluid frozen classes are after all.

Comment: The documentation explicitly states that you can't make true read-only objects in Python.